# Not able to update the constraints of my table column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing below command to make my column pname of table programs a foreign key, but the it gives me an error saying

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
  SQL> alter table programs alter column pname varchar2(20) foreign key references programmer(pname);
```

Comment: The title says SQL Server and you have tagged it SQL Server but the error is `ORA-00905` which is an Oracle error (and not SQL Server). Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Considering the error, and the use of `varchar2`, this is clearly [[tag:oracle]], not [[tag:sql-server]].

Answer (score 1):

Test case:

```
SQL> create table programmer (pname varchar2(20) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table programs (pname varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Altering the table:

```
SQL> alter table programs modify pname varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table programs add constraint fk_prog_ammer
  2    foreign key (pname) references programmer (pname);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `ADD CONSTRAINT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE programs                            -- table name
  ADD CONSTRAINT programs__pname__fk            -- constraint name
  FOREIGN KEY (pname)                           -- column to apply the constraint to
  REFERENCES programmer(pname)                  -- table and column to reference
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4ca7edef49e2bd594100deb2d8cae0de)*